# PHP: run php code every 10 seconds

Tags: php, sleep

I want run php code every 10 seconds, but my code have a problem

Because functions are random delay ( 2 seconds until 5 seconds )

I want exact run code on 10 seconds and passes function if time out or if more 5 seconds

Code :

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
     echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br />';
     get_file_content('....'); //load file from server ( make 2 seconds until 5 seconds )
     sleep(10); // sleep for 10 seconds
}
```

Result 1 :

```
2017-04-14 15:25:35
2017-04-14 15:25:46
2017-04-14 15:25:57
2017-04-14 15:26:08
2017-04-14 15:26:19
2017-04-14 15:26:30
```

Another Result :

```
2017-04-14 15:32:22
2017-04-14 15:32:34
2017-04-14 15:32:44
2017-04-14 15:33:01
2017-04-14 15:33:17
2017-04-14 15:33:29
```

I want get this result ( even load file make a long time )

Exact result :

```
2017-04-14 15:25:00
2017-04-14 15:25:10
2017-04-14 15:25:20
2017-04-14 15:25:30
2017-04-14 15:25:40
2017-04-14 15:25:50
```

Comment: Think about cronjobs.

Comment: I use cron jobs, but my server limited to 1 minute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something in the lines of :

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
$previousTime = date();
 echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br />';
 get_file_content('....'); //load file from server ( make 2 seconds until 5 seconds )
 sleep(10-(date()-$previousTime));
}
```

Comment: thank you. if file_get_content load more than 10 seconds ?

Comment: Then `I want run php code every 10 seconds, but my code have a problem` needs to be defined a bit better.

Answer (score 1):

try to count time needed to execute your function

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
    echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br />';
    $start = time();
    get_file_content('....'); //load file from server ( make 2 seconds until 5 seconds )
    $time_elapsed = time() - $start;
    if ($time_elapsed>0 || $time_elapsed<=10) sleep(10- $time_elapsed);
}
```

for more accurate, use [`microtime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php).

Answer (score 0):

Just calculate how long the `file_get_contents` took.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br />';
$start = time();
get_file_content('....'); //load file from server ( make 2 seconds until 5 seconds )
$end = time();
$diff = $end - $start;
if ($diff < 10) sleep(10 - $diff); // sleep for (10 - the amount how long the get took) seconds
// Skip if longer than 10
```

Answer (score 0):

I find solution :

```
$context = array('http' => array('timeout' => 10));
$data = file_get_contents('...',false,stream_context_create($context));
```